# MySQL statement using JOIN, ON and WHERE together doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

Database:

table #1: xx_users (id, name, user_id, location, network)

table #2: xx_questions (id, user_id, time)

Code:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
$arr= $friends['data'];
$friend_ids_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $friend) {
    $friend_ids_arr[] = $friend['id'];
}

$sql = "SELECT q.*, u.location, u.network
            FROM xx_questions q 
            JOIN xx_users u 
            ON q.user_id = u.user_id
            WHERE q.user_id = $user OR
//***       q.user_id IN (".implode(',', $friend_ids_arr).") OR
            u.location = (SELECT location FROM xx_users WHERE user_id = $user) OR
            u.network = (SELECT network FROM xx_users WHERE user_id = $user)
            ORDER BY q.time DESC";
```

The problem line is the one with the commented out asterisks by it. It's supposed to select all questions where the asker's ID matches that of one of the user's Facebook friends, but it doesn't select anything. Any idea what's wrong?

**EDIT**

The SQL output is:

```
SELECT q.*, u.location, u.network
FROM xx_questions q JOIN xx_users u
ON q.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE q.user_id = 528782060 OR q.user_id IN (123456, 234567 etc) OR
u.location = (SELECT location FROM xx_users WHERE user_id = 528782060) OR
u.network = (SELECT network FROM xx_users WHERE user_id = 528782060)
ORDER BY q.time DESC
```

Comment: It would appear that your ON statement is limiting it.  The WHERE doesn't even have a chance to find other matches, because the on statement limits the user_id.

Comment: The ON statement shouldn't limit anything... I'm sure the user_id on the question stable is a foreign key to the users table.

Comment: Can you show us what the actual SQL looks like instead of the PHP version of it?

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Just print the $sql variable: `print $sql;`

Comment: That will probably throw an error when you print the output from mysql_error(). That 'etc' in your userid is incorrect mysql syntax.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer, I just redacted that part because there were about 1000 user_ids and it would have made the code really long.

Comment: Do you have sample data? A limited dataset will do (about 5 records per table). Also, what happens when you query without the location and network conditions?

Comment: Yes I do. Excluding location and network makes no difference, i.e. the values that they would have selected aren't selected.

Answer (score 3):

The correct code is:

```
SELECT q.*, u.location, u.network
FROM xx_questions q JOIN xx_users u
ON q.user_id = u.user_id
AND q.user_id = 528782060 OR q.user_id IN (123456, 234567 etc) OR
u.location = (SELECT location FROM xx_users WHERE user_id = 528782060) OR
u.network = (SELECT network FROM xx_users WHERE user_id = 528782060)
ORDER BY q.time DESC
```